Principle like UIP on Types with Decidable Equality but for Inequality Proofs
In Coq, if I have an type with decidable equality like nat, I can show "uniqueness of identity proofs" (UIP) for that type: forall (x : nat) (Q : x = x), Q = eq_refl, or equivalently forall (x y : nat) (Q1 Q2 : x = y), Q1 = Q2. Can this be extended to inequality proofs on types with decidable equality? Specifically, can forall (x y : string) (Q1 Q2 : x <> y), Q1 = Q2 be proven in Coq without axioms?

Inequality is always a proposition, even for types without decidable equality (even for types that aren't sets!). This is because $\bot$ is a proposition, and $A \to B$ is a proposition whenever $B$ is (and $x \neq y$ is defined as $x = y \to \bot$). See HoTT book example 3.6.2.
More structured notions of apartness as used in constructive mathematics may not be propositions.

Unfortunately, this is not true in Coq because this property critically relies on function extensionality. There are models of MLTT where the negation of a type is not a proposition.

Thanks, I was about to ask if this required function extensionality. I think I can eliminate the need for the inequality by altering some definitions, but good to know it's necessary before starting.

That said, Coq is compatible both with function extensionality and proof-irrelevance for inhabitants of the Prop universe. If you assume one of these axioms you can get what you want. Do you want to be axiom-free for some specific reason?

Yes, I'm building essentially a compiler/proof of soundness for a logic that will reduce terms/props/proofs in the source logic to a proof term in Coq. Using axioms in the "compiler" stalls evaluation. Technically it's still a proof term in Coq, but a converted proof of (P -> P) will be a giant term instead of reducing all the way down to something simple and idiomatic like fun (H : Prop) => H.

You may be able to use a negation in SProp rather than Prop. Such types enjoy definitional proof irrelevance are logically equivalent to a negation in Prop.

Thanks I hadn't tried SProp before, but that works fine and seems much nicer than making a bunch of apartness types. I was happy to find Squash (a <> b) -> a <> b by factoring through an empty SProp type, so I can squash and unsquash the inequalities as needed, and I tested the terms do still fully reduce.
